# ObservableCollection and multiply NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, class, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have some problems with ObservableCollection.

Basically the problem is that, I need to change lot of properties depend on that, what was changed.

For example:

Below You can see ProductCount method, which change count(quantity) of product selected on ListView (ListView have ObservableCollection bindings).

So when I change ProductCount I also need to change DiscountPrice (when product have discount), ProductPrice (which is Count * Price), DiscountValue (f.e. if item have 50% discount, recalculate),
ReceiptSum (which is sum of all ProducPrice * ProductCount), and background if item was sent to kitchen.

```
public decimal ProductCount
{
    get 
    {
        //get count from database
        return _productCount;
    }
    set
    {
        _productCount = value;
        //update count in database
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCount");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DiscountPrice");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductPrice");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DiscountValue");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ReceiptSum);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SentToKichen");
    }
}
```

Well, everything seems to work quiet nice, but. Problem is that, that took much time to change everything. For example, on my 8 core PC, 16GB RAM, changing some value took 4 seconds. At this time application is frozen, 
which is problem I'd like to solve.

Maybe You have any idea how can I change my source code, to recalculate all values faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing that value and flagging those properies would likely not cause your issue.  What else are you doing at the same time?

Comment: Not sure, but problem could be that, when Im updating database, im getting ProductID (class), not _productID (private value). So maybe this is problem? I've added Console.Writeline on each get, and im getting 176 messages with simply add product to listview.

Comment: My guess would be that your data access is the bottleneck.  Try timing the query / update

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use asynchronous [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It will perform the asynchronous call in the UI thread, so you application shouldn't have freezes. Note that this solution is good only if you need not instant notifications.
Use Dispatcher if ProductCount is in class that inherits DependencyObject, else you can use Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.

```
public decimal ProductCount
{
    get 
    {
        //get count from database
        return _productCount;
    }
    set
    {
        _productCount = value;
        //update count in database
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCount");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DiscountPrice");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductPrice");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DiscountValue");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ReceiptSum);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SentToKichen");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is good solution, but unfortunately I need to have instant notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments in your code, I would suspect that the biggest cause of your problems is that every time a property is read, you're fetching it from the database. This means that if you have *n* properties, and you're displaying *m* records, when the UI comes to databind to all the properties, you're making *n x m* database calls, which will definitely not scale well.

A better way to do this would be to request the data in one hit, constructing your view models from the results. When you need to refresh the data (as in the case of the product count changing), then do it in one hit to the database and update the various properties - this in turn will cause the various property changed events to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can run every change you have to make in a backgroundworker to accelerate the treatment.

It is better to do your work in your viewModel, update the View then update your Model